# Ping and traceroute can resolve my IP, but real clients (Apache, Adium, ssh) cannot

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, ipv6

I have set up my DNS with [afraid.org](http://freedns.afraid.org/). I have an A record ssh.strugee.net pointing towards 71.32.87.80. I *do not* have any AAAA records set up.

When I run `ping ssh.strugee.net` or `traceroute ssh.strugee.net`, they complete DNS resolution. However, when I ssh into ssh.strugee.net, DNS resolution times out. `ping6` and `traceroute6` fail similarly. If I directly put the IP that the DNS record points to, the operation completes.

Because of this I'm pretty sure the problem is that I don't support IPv6 somehow, but I don't know how to continue my diagnostics because I don't know how the network between me and my server is constructed, and I don't know how IPv6 and IPv4 operate in that network. Is there a generic way that I can find this out? How should I continue trying to resolve this issue?

It's worth noting that my ISP is CenturyLink and I have ran the [check-ipv6](http://check-ipv6.com/) tests on the same ISP but in a different geographical location. It says that I have *no IPv6* address. I use Google Public DNS and OS X. In the OS X DNS priority list, Google DNS IPv6 is first, followed by Google DNS IPv4, followed by the default set of DNS servers (CenturyLink's).

Comment: You can ping hostname, so DNS resolution works. The hostname doesn't have an IPv6 address record so ping6 and traceroute6 cannot work. Why do you think it is a DNS problem and not i.e. your server being fire walled?

Comment: @SanderSteffann because when I enter the direct IPv4 address into the client, it works. My assumption was that the client was trying to use IPv6 and failing, but I have no way to further narrow the device causing the protocol mismatch, or even to confirm that that's what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a Linux or OS X system, you can do `ssh -v strugee@ssh.strugee.net` and see exactly why it's timing out.

I doubt that it has anything to do with IPv6. It's probably to do with your client and how you're reaching the ssh daemon on the remote side. Clear your DNS cache and double-check all of your settings.

Comment: Weird, the issue happened all the way up until I asked this question, and then it automagically started working. Probably I invalidated a cache or something in diagnostics, so I think the DNS cache was the culprit.

Comment: Your dns on ssh.strugee.net looks possibly misconfigured.  What's in /etc/resolv.conf there?  Also, turn off the ssh banner.